# Knowing when NSPopoverTouchBarItem will show its collapsed view

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nstouchbar

I have an `NSPopoverTouchBarItem` in my Touch Bar, created in Interface Builder.

The popover has a custom NSView inside it, and want to load data in it only when the view is activated, but I can't find any way to recognize when the contained `NSTouchBar` or `NSView` becomes visible.

According to docs, `NSTouchBarDelegate` does not have any delegate methods for the view appearing, either.

[image]

Which class should I subclass, or should I be monitoring `viewWillDraw` on my custom `NSView` and set up some hacky scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs were not too clear, but subclassing `NSPopoverTouchBarItem` gives you `-(void)showPopover:(id)sender` and `-(void)dismissPopover:(id)sender`.

You can then define a delegate method to tell the parent class that this popover did show.

```c
-(void)showPopover:(id)sender {
    [super showPopover:sender];
    [self.delegate touchPopoverDidShow];
}
```